# Trying to query web page in R without opening a browser

Tags: r

A little background: I'm trying to download data in bulk from the EPA's AQS network, but I am limited in the manner I can do that. As far as I know, to do this I need to send a series of web queries of the form "https://ofmext.epa.gov/AQDMRS/ws/rawDataNotify?user=*&pw=**&format=DMCSV&pc=CRITERIA&bdate=2010&edate=2010&state=YY&county=XXX" (see http://www.epa.gov/airdata/tas_URL_Query_Construction_Details_rawData.html), but that doesn't lead to a downloadable file, only to a confirmation number that will match an email I'll receive later with a link to the downloadable file.

How do I send web queries from within R, without having to resort to something like shell.exec (because I don't want to attempt to open 1000s of browser tabs)?

Comment: You're using `rawDataNotify`, don't you just want `rawData`? The documentation you linked to specifically says it will email you when done.

Comment: That would be ideal, but for some reason they have had that option disabled for at least the last six months. rawData requests yield "Synchronous (rawData) requests are not allowed at this time. Please use the asynchronous (rawDataNotify) service."